# CRA nested routes on S3 (Static Web Hosting) don't work

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router, create-react-app

I have an application with react 18 (CRA base), tailwind, react router v6 and in localhost everything works correctly (simple routes, nested, etc. either by internal navigation or directly accessing the url).

The problem is when I build and deploy to an AWS S3 bucket. I have the "Static Web Hosting" option enabled. The home page works fine, other pages like "about" or "terms" too, but when I try to access deeper nested paths (like "/path/subpath/123"), it returns a 404 - "Cannot get /path/ subpath/123").

I use BrowserRouter, Routes and Route, with using `<Outlet />` and parent and child correctly.

I would like to know if there is any chance of getting this to work or should I go another way and what would that be?

Where I enable the "Static Web Hosting" option I have tried setting redirect rules without success, adding error.html and other project-level settings like `<base href="/" />` (index.html), `homepage: "."` (package.json) or `<BrowserRouter basename="/">` (index.tsx) all of them without getting anything.

Comment: Have you reviewed the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#s3-and-cloudfront) relevant to S3 and Cloudfront?